# Kernel patches for Ubuntu16

Tags: kernel

We are still using Ubuntu16 in our company due to application dependency. and we do perform kernel patching every quarter. Last quarter done the patching with linux-image-4.4.0-1128-aws.

But not seeing any kernel updates post that. Please advise on this.

Comment: Assuming you mean Ubuntu Server 16.04.x, there will be no further kernel updates unless you have subscribed to the Extended Security Maintenance that is [part of Ubuntu Advantage](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm). Even then, you may not be getting `aws`-specific kernels.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu Core 16; it has 10 years of supported life and updates should still be occurring, however do note releases using the *year* format (eg. 16) are different to those using *year.month* (eg. 16.04) as the latter only have 5 years of *standard* support which can be extended via ESM.

Comment: Do you really need recent kernels?